# UDP Packet arrangement

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio, p2p, packet

I have implemented a P2P application using Boost C++. As you know, UDP does not guarantee packet order or even packet delivery, so this is what I thought of:

Put all the received UDP packet for one request in a link list and order it correctly so that the sequence and missing packets can be identified in a robust way. The link list is made using struct.

-Or-

I thought putting it in a vector and arranging the packets in the vector in a separate thread.

Which one is the best method? or do you'll have another best method other than window sliding.

Comment: @dani TCP hole punching doesnt work on all the NAT. So using UDP i ma on the safe side.

Comment: @dani http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/#rfc3027 here u can find in the bottom the percantage of UDP and TCP percantage of Hole punching

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of implementing your own container or sorting, why not use what's already in the standard library?

For example, you could use [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) with the sequence number as key. It's automatically sorted by key.

Or you could use [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) with your own compare function that checks the sequence number.

You should also look into [UPnP NAT traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play#NAT_traversal).

Comment: This is a good one. Ill accept it as answer after i tried it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For ensuring correct order and detect missing packets or duplicates you have to use sequence numbers or a similar approach. How can you check for the correct order on the receiving side when you put your packets in a linked list on the sending side? See the TCP protocol for an example solution on detecting missing and out of order packets (it does a little more, though).

Usually UDP is used when packet loss or reordering is acceptable. If you want to ensure these two properties even for UDP you have to do some work yourself.

Comment: Actually Link list on receivers side with the sequence number. if the link list identifies the sequence order is incorrect it will ask for the packet, that was the logic. Anyway thank i figured out a way i guess.